# How do I get the latest full hour minus one hour in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say that DateTime.Now is 13:26. How do I get 12:00 from this? I need to find the latest full hour and then go back further one hour. Or go back one hour and then find the latest full hour, whichever way... How do I achieve this in C#?

I tried `now.AddHours(-1);` to remove the first hour, but I don't know how to go back to 00 minutes. Is there a good and clean way of doing this?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the current time is `00:00:00`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour - 1);
```

This takes the current Date (with Time set to zero) and only adds the desired amount of hours back on.

No need to deal with minutes, seconds, ticks etc.

Comment: Nice, I thought about the edge case of Hour == 0, but AddHours handle negative too so it works just fine.

Comment: @Charlieface: why it seems wrong? Op wants last full hour -1, he said nothing about midnight

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're correct Tim. It works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: @Charlieface Today gives me today at 00:00:00, and then in the AddHours method the hours are added and subtracted. Tim is correct. Thank you though!

Comment: @Charlieface oooh now I see what you're saying. No I want what you suggested. But to be fair I just tested it like this `DateTime.Today.AddHours(0.5 - 1);` and it does go back to 23:30 yesterday. So I don't think there is a problem?

Comment: @Ben Scratch that, it does work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a new `DateTime` in order to truncate it, then take off an hour

```cs
var dt = DateTime.Now;
dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0, dt.Kind).AddHours(-1);
```

This correctly deals with the hour being `0`